# LinearLayout andoid, Where to add admob code

Tags: android, admob, android-linearlayout

I am adding the admob code in my layout file. I cant make it to work. Where would i add the following code:

```
...
      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/adView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          ads:adSize="BANNER"
          ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
      </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    ...


<!-- end snippet -->
```

This is my Layout file code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where ever you want the ad to appear is where you would add it

Comment: I want it yo appear at the bottom. Do i need yo change the linearlayout to relative or just add the code after webview and thats it.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this. It will show the admov below of webview.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/mainWebView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    
          <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/adView"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              ads:adSize="BANNER"
              ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
          </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This two line in your linear layout will solve the issue.

```
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```